# Looping in batch files

Tags: loops, batch-file, menu

So I created a simple menu batch file. The problem is that it waits for you to exit the program before you can enter again. How do I make it so that I can enter a number to go to a specific program, then get the prompt again to go to another program without exiting?

Comment: Place the menu and user input in a loop. Don't forget to place an option to quit the program and loop in your menu.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm not familiar with the looping for DOS

Comment: Are you really using MS-DOS? That hasn't been around for over 15 years

Answer (score 2):

A template that should come in handy:

```
@ECHO OFF

:Menu
CLS

ECHO ============= MENU =============
ECHO 1. Item 1
ECHO 2. Item 2
ECHO 3. Item 3
ECHO ----------PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT----------

SET INPUT=
SET /P INPUT=Please select a number:
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='1' GOTO Item1
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='2' GOTO Item2
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='3' GOTO Item3
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='Q' GOTO Quit

CLS

ECHO ************INVALID INPUT************
ECHO Please select a number from the Main
ECHO Menu [1-3] or select 'Q' to quit.
ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

PAUSE > NUL
GOTO Menu

:Item1
CMD1.EXE
GOTO Menu

:Item2
CMD2.EXE
GOTO Menu

:Item3
CMD3.EXE
GOTO Menu

:Quit
CLS
EXIT
```

Some remarks:

- The /P switch (SET) allows you to set a variable equal to a line of input entered by the user.
- You could consider [call](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490873.aspx), to call a label as a subroutine, instead of [goto](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490914.aspx) (some modifications to the batch file are required).

Answer (score 1):

After the program from the menu exits, add this command

```
%0
```

It is a command that has the batch file name in it, as long as `shift` has not been used, and it will relaunch the batch file without the `call` keyword.

Another option is to use a loop like this and a goto command that re-enters the start of the batch file:

If you use the `setlocal` statements then you can put them above `:loop` to stop the eventual recursion error.

```
@echo off
:loop

rem all your batch code inside here

goto :loop
```

Answer (score 0):

make your main function (the one where the user input comes in) with something like `:main` Then in all the other functions you type `goto main` (or whatever your function is called) at the end like:

```
:func1
//stuff here
goto main
```